# What is Time Complexity

Tags: time-complexity

For the last week of class we have been learning about time complexity and having online classes isn't really helping me, that and the professor isn't really going by the book.

Right now I can understand the basics like

```
count = 0
for (I = 1; I <=: I++)
    count++
//The answer is O(n)
```

but I'm totally confused on many other examples and this is how the professor is explaining

```
//Time Complexity.           cost   times
sum =0;                     //c1,     1
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)        //c2,     N+1
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)  //c3,     n*(n+1)
        sum = sum + I;      //c4,     n*n
//T(n) = c1*1 + c2(n+1) + c3 * n *(n+1) + c4 * n*n = O(n*n)
```

I don't get how you get 0(n*n)

and then for this question I don't even get it at all

```
sum =0;                     
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    sum += 10*i;        
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        sum += j;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
You might want to ask this question on https://cs.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

So, as noted in the code comment, the total time-cost of the code is
`//T(n) = c1*1 + c2(n+1) + c3 * n *(n+1) + c4 * n*n`

If you expand it out and simplify it, it'll come out to `a*n*n + b*n + c` for some numbers `a`, `b` and `c`.

The [Big O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) notation is a mathematician's way of approximating things; it takes whichever part of the formula ultimately grows fastest, and ignores any constants. Out of `a*n*n + b*n + c`, the part that grows fastest for large `n` is `a*n*n`, we ignore the `a` as a constant, so we just keep the `n*n` and write it as `O(n*n)`.

(In practice, we'd normally write it `O(n²)`, which means the same as `O(n*n)`.)

Comment: that's making a little bit more sense to me. so for the third code I gave the answer to that would be 0(n2) because its like the example you just explained, you get rid of A and b and are just left with n*n.

Comment: Yeah. The main caveat would be if the numbers we're talking about are very long (dozens or hundreds of digits, like an encryption key), in which case just multiplying or adding them takes time that depends on the length of the number. For ordinary `int` variables, addition or multiplication are constant-time.